# AWS Cloudfront availability SLA

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to design a system on AWS cloud with a certain level of SLA (say 99.99). 
One of the elements of my architecture is CloudFront and at this point, I'm struggling to understand if it's possible to increase the availability of it by introducing redundancy. Usually, it works, e.g. ECS containers or EC2 instance or RDS, but it's not possible for cloudfront (as far I a found).

What I've got so far:

[here](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/cloudfront/sla/) it says that SLA is from 99 to 99.9

[and here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html) it says that I can increase the availability having multiple Origins (CDNs), but to me, it seems like I would increase the availability of CDN, but not CloudFront service itself, wouldn't I?

Could somebody correct my understanding if it's wrong or/and explain the correct way of increasing SLA for CloudFront service?

Comment: Note also that the SLA numbers are essentially meaningless in determining either the reliability of the service or the design objectives.  [S3's SLA](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/sla/) is also 99.9% but S3 in fact [is designed for 99.99% availability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DataDurability.html), not 99.9%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you go crazy and try to design high SLA systems, think it through. 99.9% uptime is fairly easy to achieve at moderate cost. Go beyond that and your costs go up rapidly. For each addition 9, think 10x to 100x cost increase. This cost includes cloud infrastructure, management, monitoring and alerting software and the person costs. You will spend a lot of time managing systems that provide an SLA greater than 3 nines (99.9%).

99.99% utime means only 1 minute per week of downtime. This includes time that you need to spend patching operating systems, updating software, backing up, etc. Can you do all of that in 1 minute each week? If not, you won't achieve 4 nines (99.99%). Make a mistake and your 4 nines goal will become two nines.

Amazon CloudFront provides for 99.9% uptime. This is pretty good. To go higher, you need to provide multiple origins (sources for data that CloudFront caches and delivers to end users). Your origin costs just doubled in price not counting the workload to keep both origins exactly in-sync with each other 24x7. Any downtime or problems with your origins and your 4 nines just went out the window.

Comment: Thanks, @John, I'm aware of costs and complexity and I totally agree with all you wrote above. But the question is is it possible to get higher SLA for CloudFront or not? if Yes then how? Are redundant origins really increase SLA of CloudFront or it remains with the same SLA inspite of count of origins?

Comment: Amazon's SLA is 99.9 provided your origins can also provide 99.9 or better. If your origins are 99.99 Amazon's SLA is still 99.9.

Comment: actually, it's not even 99.9 it's rather 99 (goes from this link https://aws.amazon.com/ru/cloudfront/sla/). So it seems like a single point of failure and there is no option to make it better (I'm not saying it's bad or it's always necessary, just want to know the numbers precisely). I will wait a few days and if nobody come up with the better answer/ideas i will mark yours

Comment: my bad it's 99.9, sorry

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, this will introduce more costs and complexity, so here goes my idea:

You can increase availability with the help of Route53 (which has a SLA of 100%).

First, I would have a copy of the objects you're serving on Cloudfront on a different service, for example, EC2 (see how complexity starts to grow).

Then you'd need to setup a failover routing policy. Basically Route53 would check the health of your Cloudfront distribution and if it's not healthy then the traffic would failover to EC2.

Now your SLA will go up to 99.89% (99.99% EC2 * 99.9% Cloudfront)

Comment: That SLA went down.

Comment: 99.89% (HA) is less than 99.9% (CloudFront alone)

Comment: Lol. The calculation should be as follows:

1 - (Probability that both are down)

Assuming independence for failure modes:

1 - (.0001 EC2 * .001 Cloudfront) = 1 - .000001 = .999999

Answer (score 0):

Think of CloudFront as CDN (similar to Akamai and other CDN). I.e. it is a cache for static content that can reside on S3 or other origins. Even if CloudFront goes down your system is still 99.99% available (if designed that way), because your system boundary is VPC edge and not CloudFront, Route53, S3 etc. (these are regarded as external interfaces by your system and are in public zone unless you build a private connection to them).